# Open all files in an array and add file contents to new array

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get the contents of all the files in a folder of a particular type and add their contents to an array. Since `File.open` only accepts strings I'm not sure how to do this. The closest I've figured is something along the lines of:

```
Dir.glob(*).each do|file|
  filearray = File.open(file).read
```

But beyond that I'm at a loss of how to get the output into an array variable for use by other parts of code later.

Comment: How big are the files in this directory? This could halt your system.

Comment: There are 14 files and the largest is 800kb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have it, but what about something like this instead?

```
filearray = Dir.glob('*').select { |f| File.file?(f) }.map { |f| File.read(f) }
```

The `select` bit just makes sure that you're pulling in files only (not directories).  If you have a particular file extension in mind, you could add that to the `glob` call too - for instance, if you're looking for all .rb files, you could use `'*.rb'` instead of `'*'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s_folder_path = 'C:/Test'
a_files = []

Dir.foreach(s_folder_path).each do |file|
  a_files << File.open("#{s_folder_path}/#{file}").read if file != "." && file != ".."
end

puts a_files.inspect
```